# How can I preserve the text spatial integrity while using the OCR tool from google's cloud vision or document AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, tesseract, google-cloud-vision, cloud-document-ai

I am using OCR tool provided by Google's Document AI to extract text from images such as the one given below:
[image]

My goal is to create a dataframe with all the metrics given such as Rate, RR, PR as columns that are filled in with the succeeding values. This can easily be done with the help of a regular expression that records numeric values present after a keyword such as "Rate". The problem, however, is when I use the document AI OCR to extract the text, it prints it as follows:
[image]

How or what can I do to enable the document ocr to print the text exactly as seen in the image?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you try it with the [form parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example, it would make sense to try the [Form Parser processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/form-parser) as suggested by [kiran-mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17258510/kiran-mathew).

This processor can detect key-value pairs and tables, which can be extracted from the Document AI response with the code samples shown in [Handle the processing response > Forms and Tables](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables).

The [Document AI Toolbox Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/toolbox#:%7E:text=Convert%20Tables%20to%20a%20Pandas%20Dataframe%20or%20CSV.) also has built in functions for converting extracted tables to Pandas Dataframes.

In a more general case, you can get the layout bounding box detected by Document AI in the `boundingPoly` field for `paragraphs`, `lines`, `tokens`, etc. This contains the coordinates for each element on the page. [Handle the processing response > Text, layout, and quality scores](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#text_layout_and_quality_scores) describes the structure.